# How does the gravitational field of a massive body affect the orbit of that body around yet another massive body?

Tags: general-relativity

If I understand the relativistic explanation of gravitation - that it is curvature of spacetime - then a particle left alone will travel along that curved spacetime in a path that depends on the local curvature at each instant in time (right?).  If so, then the orbit of a small body without significant effects on that local curvature is something I can get my head around.  However, if I have a body that non-negligibly curves spacetime (say...two black holes?  But I expect that a planet around a star would fit my bill here), does the curvature caused by the smaller body affect its path?  This sounds to me like it would be a weird self-interaction that wouldn't have any effect, but in my mind I am divorcing the curvature of spacetime from the force-interaction that bodies experience in that curved spacetime, and thus I am having trouble wrapping my head around it.

Comment: Are we ignoring the gravitational force that the sun feels from the planet here?

Comment: you might want to see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-body_problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the gravitational field of the smaller body does have an impact on its own orbit. This effect is known as the “gravitational self force”. The gravitational field of the smaller body can be separated in two parts. The first is the “direct” field of the body. This is akin to the field it would produce in complete isolation. It is symmetrical and has no impact on the body’s orbit.

The second is the “tail” part and can be thought of as the difference to the body’s gravitational field due to sitting in the background curvature caused by the larger body as compared to sitting in a perfectly flat environment. It is this part that is responsible for the gravitational self force.